# Fermion parity vs gauge symmetry

Tags: gauge-theory, vacuum, fermions, parity, chirality

Take for instance a 4d gauge theory with a fermion $\psi$ in some representation of the gauge group $G$ and say that I want to study the fate of the "non ABJ-anomalous" part of the axial symmetry $U(1)_A$, when going to the IR. Without susy, it is not trivial to know what condenses in the vacuum; is this a fermion bilinear ? is this a high-order condensate ? does anything condenses at all ?

One thing for sure is that the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ fermion parity $(-1)^F$ is part of the axial symmetry group and corresponds to $\psi \rightarrow - \psi$. Moreover, this transformation is part of the Lorentz group, since it is a $2\pi$ space rotation of the fermion. Hence I would expect to always have at least a fermion bilinear condensing in the vacuum, in order to preserve this $\mathbb{Z}_2$ fermion parity.

However, some say that in some cases the fermion parity is part of the gauge group, typically if the gauge group $G$ has a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ subgroup in its center. Is this true ? For $G=SU(N)$, it would be that the fermion parity is part of the gauge redundancies for any even $N$. In these cases, should I still expect a fermion bilinear to condense in the vacuum ? Another question is should one generally mod out the full global symmetry group by this fermion parity ?

Comment: Some say? Who say?

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə I can't find the paper anymore, but my main concern is to figure out whether it's true or no

Comment: Well, the point of my comment was that if you had put a link maybe someone would be able to say if it's true in that specific case of if it isn't and why. As it stands your statement isn't true. But it is not unheard of that someone gauges it. (and in that case you get a dual, global, quantum $\mathbb{Z}_2$)